# Trouble with updating Ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm having a problem where when I open up Terminal in Mac OS X, and type `ruby -v`, I get:

```
➜  ~  ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

I used RVM to install a more recent version of Ruby, and when I ask it to list installed versions of Ruby, I get:

```
➜  ~  rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

So, I simply type this to use ruby-1.9.3-p286:

```
➜  ~  rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p286
Using /Users/patrickestabrook/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286
➜  ~  ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

The problem is that whenever I log out and open up terminal again, it sets my Ruby version back to ruby 1.8.7.  How can I get it to just stay at ruby-1.9.3-p286?

Answer (score 3):

What you have is `system` default version so do following it will set the default:

```
rvm --default use ruby-1.9.3-p286
```

`--default` will set your default version. When you do `rvm list` ruby with `*` indicates your `default` one.

If you don't get it. Try `rvm default`

Comment: This didn't work.  When I logout and log back in, it still shows that I'm using Ruby 1.8.7.  Ugh this is so annoying!

Comment: what do u have in `.bashrc` about `rvm`??

Comment: if you have `.rvm`(rvm installed) in your home directory. You should have `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in `.bashrc` to load ur rvm in to a shell.

Comment: What directory should .bashrc be in?

Comment: In home directory (i.e) `vim ~/.bashrc`. And also check where is your rvm.